# R Shiny daterange input on R Markdown Title

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown, titlebar

I am using the robobook rmdformat R Markdown template. My markdown doc has some shiny inputs. I would like to have a dateRangeInput variable next to the title on the TOC legend off to the side. That way the user can scroll down and change the date from any part of the document. This obviously did not work, but I tried this below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  title: 'shiny::dateRangeInput("riskdate", "Select Risk Date Range",start = 
          lubridate::today()-1825,format ="yyyy-mm-dd"))'
  runtime: shiny
  output: rmdformats::robobook
```

Answer (score 0):

With just a little bit of R code, we have an Rmarkdown document with `rmdformats::robobook` output document style. and `runtime: shiny` in the YAML as well. Shiny allows for extreme customization if you know CSS, HTML, JS. Used [This link for Shiny date example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/dateRangeInput.html)

[image]

````
---
title: "Rmarkdown shiny by Date"
author: "StackOverflow"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmdformats::robobook
runtime: shiny
---


```{r echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
shinyApp(

  ui = fluidPage(
    dateInput("date1", "Date:", value = "2022-02-16")
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {},

  options = list(width = 500)
)

```
````

Comment: Thanks for the post Daniel! However I am trying to add the date input on the table of contents. My goal is to have the date input floating as the user scrolls down. There are multiple charts and tables that are controlled by the date input and I thought to prevent the user from scrolls up to the beginning to change the date it would be nice for them to be able to just change it on the TOC.